# Property [students] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.6

So i have relationship declared on the parents Model as

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Parents extends Model
{
  protected $fillable = [
      'firstName',
      'middleName',
      'lastName',
      'phoneNumber',
      'gender',
  ];
  public function students(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Student','parent_student','parentId','studentId');
  }

}
```

with the anchor table `parent_student` and a students table with the column `classId`. here is the students model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends Model
{
  //
  protected $fillable = [
    'firstName',
    'middleName',
    'lastName',
    'regNo',
    'gender', 
    'dob',        
    'classId',
  ];

  public function parents(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Parents','parent_student','studentId','parentId');
  }

  public function classes()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Classes','classId');
  }
}
```

what i am tring to achieve is to get the email addresses for parents with students in one class eg class 1, which i pass the classId from a dropdown select in a form on the view to the controller.

Here is my controller.

```
public function submitEmail(Request $request)
    {
      $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'class' => 'required|integer',
        'message' => 'string|max:255',
        'subject' => 'string|max:255',
      ]);
      $class = $request->input('class');
      $message = $request->input('message');
      $subject = $request->input('subject');
  $parents = Parents::all();
        $parents = Parents::where($parents->students->classId,"=",$class)->get();
        die($parents);


}
```

I am fairly new to laravel and this is the far i have gone so far.Any suggestions would be much appreciated.(I am using laravel 5.6)

Comment: I'm not fully sure your datamodel is correct. Can you add the `Classes` model? Why is the model plural? Shouldn't you have `Class` and a Student belongs to Many Class(es) ? Also it's not really clear where you error occurs. Add the full error message please. Your where clause seems very wrong as you refer to the classId which is probably not an attribute of your Parent model. Also you query parents in order to build a where clause on the parents model which doesn't seem to be correct aswell. You should go step by step instead doing it all in once if you're new.

Comment: pls specify table names with their foreign keys

Comment: Thanks @FrankProvost, am still new and getting the hang of it,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line

```
$parents->students
```

is where your problem is. `$parents` is a `Collection` (array) of `Parents` models, not a single `Parents`<sup>1</sup> model. To get a single `classId`, you need to use a Loop:

```
foreach($parents AS $parent){
  ... // Should be able to access $parent->students without issue;
}
```

Next, you're trying to access `->classId` of `$parent->students`, which is the same issue. `$parent->students` is a `Collection`, and not a single `Student`<sup>2</sup> model. You'd need another loop to get the `classId`:

```
foreach($parents AS $parent){
  foreach($parent->students AS $student){
    ... // Should be able to access `$student->classId` without issue
  }
}
```

But, this still doesn't solve your core issue. It's important to know when you're accessing a `Collection` vs a single `Model`, so keep that in mind.

All of that aside, it sounds like you're trying to get all the Parents of Students in Class of `$class` (passed from your `<form>`). To accomplish this, you can use `->whereHas()`, as below:

```
$parents = Parents::whereHas("students", function($query) use($class){
  $query->where("classId", "=", $class);
})->with(["students" => function($query) use($class){
  $query->where("classId", "=", $class);
}])->get();
```

What this does, is queries the `parents` table for any student records that have a class with an id of `$class`.

Note that `whereHas` and `with` contains the same subquery to constrain and eager-load each `Parents` collection of `Students` to what's required.

Sidenote: Your `classes()` relationship on `Student` has an issue. Since it's a `belongsTo()` method, it should be `class()` (singular), as `$student->classes` would only return a single `Class` model.

---

<sup>1</sup> Pay attention to naming conventions. `Parents` should be `Parent`; Model names are singular.
<sup>2</sup> You named the `Student` Model right, so be consistent.

Comment: Thank you,this worked perfectly, i am still new to laravel and this was my first project away from he tutorials and this helps me a lot.

Comment: No worries, happy to help. You'll get the hang of Collections, Models, Relationships, Queries, etc etc as you use it more and more, so keep at it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
$parents = Parents::with(['students' => function($query) use ($class){
    $query->where('classId',$class);
}])->get();
```

Instead of:

```
$parents = Parents::where($parents->students->classId,"=",$class)->get();
```

Then instead of `die($parents)` use `dd($parents)`